# Why isnt product of nth roots of unity always 1

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

I know product of nth roots of unity is 1 or -1 depending whether n is odd or even.
But in this way I am getting 1. Where am I wrong?

$ \text{Let }\alpha = \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} + \iota \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n} \text{ be a root of }x^n=1 \\
\text{Then product of nth roots will be } 1\cdot \alpha \cdot \alpha^2 ... \alpha^{n-1} = \alpha^{\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}}\\
=\left( \alpha^n \right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\\
=1^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \text{......By the definition of alpha ??}\\
=1 $

I can see this doesn't even work for n=2.

Comment: Using a similar logics, $$-1=(-1)^{2/2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1.$$

Comment: My detailed answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4111792/21813)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following: 
$$(-1)^1 = (-1)^{2\cdot \frac{1}{2}} = ((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{2}=1^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1$$
You did something like that. $n(n-1)/2$ is always an integer when $n$ is a natural number, but when you take out the $n$ you are left with $(n-1)/2$ which is not always an integer, which messes things up when $n$ is even. In short, the rule $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ does not always hold for complex numbers, in particular when $b$ or $c$ are not integers.

Comment: As you showed by your example, $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ doesn't even always hold for real numbers

Answer (score 3):

$(n-1)/2$ is not an integer, so $1^{(n-1)/2}$ involves the square-root, which might be positive or negative.  You have to look more closely to decide which.
It is a bit like $-1=(-1)^{2/2}=1^{1/2}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\alpha^{n(n-1)/2}=(\alpha^{n/2})^{n-1}$$

Now $\alpha^{n/2}=\cdots=-1$