# Ambiguity in product of all $n$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, radicals

I was studying the product of $n$th roots of unity, and the proof in the book went like this:
$$1\cdot a\cdot a^2\cdot\cdots\cdot a^{n-1}
\\=a^{0+1+2+3...+n-1}
\\=a^{n(n-1)/2}
\\=(\cos\frac{2\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2\pi}n)^{n(n-1)/2}
\\=(\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi)^{(n-1)/2}
\\=(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi)^{n-1}
\\=(-1)^{n-1}
\\=\begin{cases}-1 &\text{if n is even;} \\1 &\text{if n is odd.}\end{cases}$$

But instead of doing that, if we simplified directly from $(\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi)^{(n-1)/2},$ we'd get
$$1^{(n-1)/2}=1.$$

So, where exactly was I wrong?
I think the problem basically boils down to
$$(-1)^x=1^{x/2}=1.$$
Obviously, this is wrong, but I can't spot where it is wrong. Also, why is it wrong?

Comment: the problem is that $1^{1/2} = \pm 1$

Comment: When you say $1^{\frac{x}{2}}$, you mean a number whose square is $1^x$.

Comment: $1^\frac{1}{2}$ is an ambiguous term, both $1$ and $-1$ fulfill $x^2=1$
Usually the square root is defined to be the positive number but that is a choice!

Comment: $1^{1/2}$ is nothing but the square root of 1. Surely, if that is defined as the positive square root, it will be equal to 1 and not -1, and so there's no ambiguity?

Comment: When you write $(-1)^x=1^\frac{x}{2}$, you are implicitly using that (for example when you put in $x=1$)

Comment: I think the answer is the opposite of what you say, when $n$ is odd the product is $+1$. (The case $n=1$ gives an easy check.)

Comment: Yeah, nice catch. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n(n-1)/2$ is an integer. After all, it is a sum of integers.

I think the book makes a blunder by factoring $n(n-1)/2$ into an integer factor $n$ and another factor $(n-1)/2$ that might not be an integer.
By doing this, it reaches a step where it must evaluate $1^{(n-1)/2}.$
This is not necessarily $1$ as you claim.
But it also is not necessarily $-1$ when $n$ is even as the book claims.
As several other answers have pointed out, when dealing with complex numbers we have to treat raising a number to a fractional power as a multivalued function,
and in the case of $n$ even we simply cannot say whether $1^{(n-1)/2}$
is $1$ or $-1.$

What the book's argument does, in fact, is use the fallacious "identity"
$z^{ab} = (z^a)^b$ for complex $z$ and arbitrary rational $a$ and $b.$
The equality sign before $(\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi)^{(n-1)/2}$ is invalid.

If instead we recall that $n(n-1)/2$ is an integer, we can immediately multiply the argument of $\cos\frac{2\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2\pi}n$  by this integer with no ambiguity and no weird multivalued outputs. Quite simply,

\begin{align}
\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2\pi}n\right)^{n(n-1)/2}
&= \cos\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2\cdot\frac{2\pi}n\right)
    + i\sin\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2\cdot\frac{2\pi}n\right) \\
&= \cos\left((n-1)\pi\right) + i\sin\left((n-1)\pi\right) \\
&= \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{$n$ even,} \\
\phantom{-}1 & \text{$n$ odd.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice proof. So, what youre saying is $=(\cos 2\pi +i\sin 2\pi)^{n-1/2} $ is invalid because of the ambiguity that the square root of a complex number gives all the roots, but the square root of a real number ( in this case, $1$) only gives the positive root, hence leading us to lose some answers??

Comment: If you interpret the root as a principal square root, yes, you can lose answers. Even if the principal square root had happened to be the correct answer it would still be an insufficient proof unless you had some other way of confirming that that root was correct and the other wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the complex world, the exponent $\frac1n$ does not conventionally output *just* the principal root, because such a convention isn't as useful as in the real world, and because there isn't a universally-good way to define principal root in the complex world.

   So, $$1^{\frac14}=-i,1,i,-1;$$ similarly, for **even** $n,$ $$1^{(n-1)/2}\\=\pm1\\\neq1.$$
2. In general, a number raised to a non-integer (including complex) power may have multiple values.

   Further, when $z\in\mathbb C$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R,$
   $$\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^z=e^{z\,i\left(\theta \color{#C00}{+2k\pi}\right)}.\tag{*}$$

   A corollary is that when $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R,$
   $$\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^m=e^{i\,m\theta}.\tag{#}$$
3. The proof supplied by the book is misleadingly
   hand-wavy, with errors at its $4$th and $5$th ‘=’ (apparently misapplying De Moivre's theorem). Here's a
   clearer version: $$1\cdot a\cdot a^2\cdot\cdots\cdot a^{n-1}
   \\=a^{0+1+2+3...+n-1} \\=a^{n(n-1)/2}
   \\=\left(e^{i\frac{2\pi}n}\right)^{n(n-1)/2}$$
   $$=e^{i(n-1)\pi}\tag {applying (#)} \\=\begin{cases}e^{i(\pi)} &\text{if n is even;} \\e^{i(0)} &\text{if n is odd}\end{cases} \\=\begin{cases}-1 &\text{if n is even;} \\1 &\text{if n is odd.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

First,
$$  (-1)^3 = -1  \text{,}  $$
not $1$, as your last paragraph would have us believe.

Here is *a* difficulty.  Notice that $$  \mathrm{e}^{0 \mathrm{i}} = 1 = \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi  \mathrm{i}}  \text{.}  $$
When we take *the* complex square root of these three numbers, we use the *convention* that we obtain a number with the square root of the magnitude and half the argument.  So we should see \begin{align*}
\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{0 \mathrm{i}}} &= \mathrm{e}^{(0/2) \mathrm{i}} = \mathrm{e}^{0 \mathrm{i}} = 1 \text{,}  \\
\sqrt{1} &= 1  \text{, and} \\
\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi  \mathrm{i}}} &= \mathrm{e}^{\pi  \mathrm{i}} = -1  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
Of course, these three things are not all equal.  To regain equality, we would need to obtain all the square roots of $1$: $\{-1, 1\}$ for all three of these, so we cannot trust the convention to solve all of our problems.

A less confusing way to proceed is to recognize that any complex number has infinitely many magnitude-argument representations.  Perhaps we should look at how those behave.  Throughout, $k$ is permitted to range over the integers.  Arithmetic of magnitudes is arithmetic over the reals, so uses the usual convention that real square roots return nonnegative results.  (This is not a significant restriction, since generally we should be keeping all magnitudes nonnegative, and in the present, $1$ is the only magnitude we will have.)
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{0 + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k} = \{1\}  \\
1^{1/2} &= 1^{1/2} \mathrm{e}^{0/2 + \pi \mathrm{i} k} = 1 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{0 + \pi \mathrm{i} k} = \{-1,1\} \\
\end{align*}
That is, if we keep track of all the magnitude-argument aliases of our various numbers, we get all of their roots at once.

Let's try this with the development you recite.  Since $a$ is the $n^\text{th}$ root of unity of least positive argument,
$$  a = (\cos(2\pi/n) + \mathrm{i}\sin(2\pi/n)) = \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k}  \text{.}  $$
We first need that
\begin{align*}
n(n-1)/2 + n &= (n^2 - n)/2  \\
    &= (n^2 + n)/2 - n  \\
    &= n(n+1)/2 - n
\end{align*}
and $a^{-n} = 1$.  (We don't *actually* need this.  We can keep "$n-1$" through to the end.  However, to parallel the work you recite, ...)
\begin{align*}
a^{n(n-1)/2} &= (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{n(n-1)/2}  \\
    &= (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{n(n+1)/2 - n}  \\
    &= (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{n(n+1)/2} (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{-n}  \\
    &= (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}/n + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{n(n+1)/2}  \\
    &= (\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} + 2 n \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{(n+1)/2}  \\
    &= (\mathrm{e}^{\pi \mathrm{i} + n \pi \mathrm{i} k})^{n+1}  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{(n+1)\pi \mathrm{i}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{n(n+1) \pi \mathrm{i} k}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{(2j+1)\pi \mathrm{i}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{2j(2j+1) \pi \mathrm{i} k}  ,&  n = 2j, j \in \Bbb{Z}  \\
\mathrm{e}^{(2j+2)\pi \mathrm{i}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{(2j+1)(2j+2) \pi \mathrm{i} k}  ,&  n = 2j+1, j \in \Bbb{Z}  
\end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
(-1) \cdot (1)  ,&  n = 2j, j \in \Bbb{Z}  \\
(1) \cdot (1)  ,&  n = 2j+1, j \in \Bbb{Z}  
\end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
-1  ,&  n \text{ is even}  \\
1  ,&  n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
correcting the error in the last line of your recitation.  Notice that the calculation shows that during the sequence of operations the "${} + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k$" is modified in various ways, but at the end, all of the alternatives produced by varying $k$ have been collapsed back to a single complex number.  During the process, this was not always true.  As $k$ ranges over the integers, $\mathrm{e}^{\pi \mathrm{i} + n \pi \mathrm{i} k}$ is $\{-1\}$ if $n$ is even and is $\{-1,1\}$ if $n$ is odd.